# Question about how to grant Secrets Manager access permission to call Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, credentials, aws-secrets-manager

I'm currently following this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-secrets-manager/) to create a Lambda function with this Generic Rotation Function Template, the first step is to create an AWS CloudFormation change set based on the generic rotation function template.

By doing this, I need to enter the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for the generic rotation function template with AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI), the ARN is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_available-rotation-templates.html#sar-template-generic). The command is :`arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:297356227824:applications/SecretsManagerRotationTemplate`

I'm very new to AWS CLI, I think I've installed it, but I tried to execute this command in CMD, it fave me error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`
Am I missing something? What directory should I use to execute this command? Many thanks.

Comment: Can you paste your cli command here?

Comment: @PubuduJayawardana This is the command ```arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:297356227824:applications/SecretsManagerRotationTemplate```, it's from this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_available-rotation-templates.html#sar-template-generic

Comment: That's just an ARN (Amazon Resource Name). That's not a command. What is the AWS CLI command you are trying?

Comment: @MarkB I'm following this link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-secrets-manager/, it's the first step, it says 'Enter the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for the generic rotation function template with AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation is confusing. The first step tells you to "enter the ARN" but there is nothing to actually enter it into. Just skip to step 2 where it gives you the full command to run, including the ARN.

Comment: Ah thanks, a quick question about the command in the second step, '--stack-name' is the new stack name I defined right? Or should I go to Cloudformation and create one manually and point the name in this command

Comment: @Cecilia stack-name is just whatever you want the name to be once it is created by the command.

Comment: Just a follow-up question, in the command, ```--parameter-overrides '[{"Name":"endpoint","Value":"https://secretsmanager.region.amazonaws.com"},{"Name":"functionName","Value":"MySecretsManagerRotationFunction"}]'``` contains the secret manager endpoint URL, is it the URL  in the ```host``` parameter in the secret? and should I remain ```"Name":"endpoint"```the same? Sorry if I have too many questions, I'm very new to AWS

Comment: As the documentation states on that page, you need to change `https://secretsmanager.region.amazonaws.com` to whatever the secrets manager endpoint is for your region. For example if your region is `us-east-1 (Virginia)` then the value should be `https://secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. This is unrelated to the `host` parameter you are talking about.

Comment: I got this error ```Error parsing parameter '--parameter-overrides': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:``` when executing this command, do you know what's going on here?

Comment: Looks like it should be `Name=string,Value=string` instead of what the page you linked says. That guide you are following appears to be pretty bad, and you should submit feedback. I suggest comparing the command against the AWS CLI documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/serverlessrepo/create-cloud-formation-change-set.html

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that SM supports my RDS database (Aurora MySQL) and I don't have to follow this and create through CloudFormation, I can just use the rotation function template for MySQL, but thank you very much anyway.